# mutex/lock/semaphore in SML

Tags: multithreading, sml, smlnj

Does SML have a mutex/lock/semaphore/etc library? I couldn't find one anywhere in the docs. I couldn't even find a multithreading library anywhere. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the standard as such. However, if you are using SML/NJ or MLton, then they both provide [Concurrent ML](http://cml.cs.uchicago.edu), an advanced concurrency library with first-class synchronisation events. Poly/ML also has its own [Thread](http://www.polyml.org/docs/Threads.html) module.